# Is there a diagram of different nozzle diameters to scale?

Tags: engine-design, engineering, nozzle

I am looking for a diagram that shows the different diameters of various nozzle openings, including Rocketdyne's F1 (150 inches) SpaceX's Merlin (66 inches), the Air Force's Delta IV Heavy, and NPO Energomash's Proton-M (59 inches). Those ones are rather popular and easier to find, but I am wondering if anyone has a list of different engines and their different characteristics.

My theory is that engine size compared to launch vehicle weight is going to decrease over time, especially as efficiency rises. If I had some more data I might be able to show this to be true. Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

Let me clarify a little bit. I want to see if, for a given launch vehicle weight, the diameter of the engine nozzle has decreased slowly over time, as engines become more efficient and use lighter materials. As such, if I have different nozzle diameters at different time periods of high engine usage, there may be a trend through time. Plus, it would just be cool to see this information, and see how different engine characteristics have changed through time. I want to see what sort of trends like this exist among other engine characteristics, to see how the technology evolves. I would also make this comparison against thrust.

Lastly, I am really interested in engine design, and understanding how technological advancements change the dimensions and components will help a lot.

Comment: What is your theory exactly?  What are the dimensions of engine "size"?  In general your theory sounds incorrect.  The total nozzle exit area would like to be proportional to thrust, which is proportional to weight.  However the area at the end of the rocket grows as about the 2/3 power of the weight.  So nozzles end up being constrained by the vehicle, since they'd like to be bigger.  Inefficiencies have to be accepted for under-expanded flow.

Comment: I wish some of the awesome infographic makers like at Space.com, might consider doing engines like you suggest.  I would be really curious to see an F-1 vs an RD-170.

Comment: Let me clarify a little bit. I want to see if, for a given weight, the diameter of the engine nozzle has decreased slowly over time, as engines become more efficient and use lighter materials. As such, if I have different nozzle diameters at different time periods of high engine usage, there may be a trend through time. Plus, it would just be cool to see this information, and see how different engine characteristics have changed through time.

Comment: I still don't see how this is any different that asking if performance over area ratio has increased as rocket engine design evolved. Which boils down to, have rocket engines evolved. Which in turn is the same as asking whether we've been burning all the R&D money for nothing during all these years. I agree, it would be interesting to see some graphs how they did tho. But if, I have no doubt.

Comment: Yes, that is just an example which I believe to be true. I want to see what trends (if any) exist for other engine characteristics as well, and I just need data on these for different engines.

Comment: The nozzle size you have for the Merlin is way off, at 1m67 you can't fit 9 of them on a stage with a diameter of 3m66. The first stage Merlins are around 93 cm (no diameter has been published by SpaceX, so this has been measured from photos). The Merlin Vac may be 1m67, but again, no size info has been published that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Hobbes: You are generally getting more surface area covered when [packing more small circles in a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle) than if you use bigger ones (except for n=1). So 9 smaller engines will have a higher total nozzle area than, say, 3 or 4 big ones.

Comment: ...and in the end, the diameter doesn't mean all that much, because you can modernize a rocket by decreasing the nozzle diameter while retaining the same fuel flux and increasing exhaust speed, or you can simultaneously increase the exhaust speed and fuel flux while keeping the diameter the same, so that you get better thrust and better ISp out of the same diameter. Also... where would that place Soyuz launch vehicle with its 20 basic and 12 vernier combustion chambers?

Answer (score 2):

I could not find any diagram, but here is one:

[image]

Wikipedia's [list of orbital rocket engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_orbital_rocket_engines) is a good place to start, just click the link to their main article. Most of them have their diameter in their fact box:

[image]

Be aware that determining the optimal nozzle diameter is complicated, especially for the first stage, due to atmospheric backpressure

Comment: The Merlin 1D has a diameter of about 90 cm. At 168 cm, you [wouldn't be able to fit 9 of them](http://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=32983.msg1139226#msg1139226) under a stage that's 366 cm in diameter. 168 could be the diameter of the Merlin Vacuum version, but I've never seen good data for that.

Comment: @Hobbes fixed it!